# Flutter Invalid plugin specification path_provider_windows

Tags: flutter

when I try to add libraries in which cache images from server like :
cached_network_image
flutter_advanced_networkimage

the lib download to lib folder but project can't be build and show error:

Invalid plugin specification path_provider_windows.
Invalid "windows" plugin specification.

here is my pubspec.yaml

```
environment:
sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
 flutter:
sdk: flutter
flutter_localizations:
sdk: flutter
get_it: ^2.0.1
flutter_bloc: ^4.0.0
equatable: ^0.4.0
dartz: ^0.8.6
data_connection_checker: ^0.3.4
dio: ^3.0.10
shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4
image_picker: ^0.6.7
#flutter_advanced_networkimage: ^0.7.0
#cached_network_image: ^2.3.2+1

google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.28+1

permission_handler: ^5.0.0+hotfix.8

url_launcher: ^5.4.10
mailto: ^0.2.0+1

shamsi_date: ^0.9.0

firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
firebase_analytics: ^5.0.2
firebase_messaging: ^6.0.16
firebase_crashlytics: ^0.1.3+3

dev_dependencies:
 flutter_test:
 sdk: flutter
 gen_lang: 0.1.3
 mockito: ^4.1.0
 flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3"
```

Comment: Could you post pubspec.yaml and run in verbose mode for output?

Comment: @Kate question edited, .yaml added

Answer (score 0):

This isn't technically me answering the question however the dev team have picked up on this issue and they are in the process of fixing it

Here is the github link to their fix: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/66158

EDIT:

According to the issue logged on Github a fix would be to `pub upgrade` which would theoretically upgrade you to the latest working version of `path_provider`, not sure if this works though I have yet to try it myself

Comment: If you include the workaround linked in that issue here it could be a good answer in the meantime. Even better if you update the answer once it's been resolved!